# Slight differences in MD5 hash of file between VC++ and Python

Tags: python, visual-c++, md5

I have two pieces of code, both calculating the MD5 hash of the exact same files. One is in C++ (stolen from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, and a bit too long to copy-paste here), the other one is in Python:

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
f = open("file", 'rb')
while True:
    data = f.read(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    md5.update(data)
hash = md5.hexdigest()
```

At first sight, the two hashes seemed to be equal, yet they really aren't:

`987ab42efb655a62249651907daef16e` (Python) - `9874eb5a24610de1e49651907daef16e` (C++)
`33ee1578f082db63f2f590ca210f419e` (Python) - `33e5802b3250a1f1e2f590ca210f419e` (C++)

So what could be causing these differences?

#### Fixed:

Thanks to Duncan's comment.

Okay, I think [this is the data the OP is using](http://code.google.com/p/ubuntugames/source/browse/branches/cs2d-0.1.1.9/debian/cs2d/DEBIAN/md5sums?spec=svn6&r=6):

```
33ee1578f082db63f2f590ca210f419e usr/local/games/cs2d/sfx/items/drop.wav
987ab42efb655a62249651907daef16e  usr/local/games/cs2d/sfx/items/ammo.wav
```

Comment: Can you post an example file as well that we can check against? That way we can at least tell you which of the two methods is wrong.

Comment: what's the result of command `md5sum file`?

Comment: Also, have you checked the first comment on the MS example? Maybe their code is buggy.

Comment: Does adding "U" to the file mode change anything? The Python and C++ code may be handling newlines differently.

Comment: @chepner, it's already opened in binary mode `rb`.

Comment: @kev in both cases the result equals the hash created by Python. So that means the C++ code is somehow malfunctioning...

Comment: @Niklas B. Increasing buffer size for the NULL byte seems not to make any difference for the hash.

Comment: @Banaan have you changed the C++ code in any way from the linked page? The fact that part of the hash matches points very strongly to the problem being with how you output the result: as though something is corrupting part of the buffer that contains the hash before you can display it.

Comment: @Banaan: Yeah, that comment is nonsense, as I just noticed. Is the file on a local hard driver and you execute the two programs from the same machine? Or are you sharing this over the network somehow? This really sounds like a binary/text mode issue, although you correctly use `'rb'`. Maybe some abstraction layer is causing this? Or maybe the MS code is actually misbehaving (I'll check it out).

Comment: @Duncan: You're right, using an exact copy of the page generates the correct hashes. Instead of `printf`, I use `sprintf_s` to write the hash to a char array. Rewriting that fixed the problem, I suppose I had a typo somewhere? Thanks for the help (though I can't accept an answer now)

Comment: How can anyone evaluate this without the data to replicate the error?

Comment: @hughdbrown: intuition, I guess.

Comment: @Niklas B.: Or google the MD5 hashes. Oh look, both of them on the same page. http://code.google.com/p/ubuntugames/source/browse/branches/cs2d-0.1.1.9/debian/cs2d/DEBIAN/md5sums?spec=svn6&r=6

Comment: @hughdbrown: Could just be a coincidence.

Comment: @hughdbrown. Lucky for OP the files are not embarrassing :)